# Three gentlemen and three ladies are candidates for two vacancies.A voter has to vote for two candidates.In how many ways can on cast his vote?

Tags: combinatorics

> Three gentlemen and three ladies are candidates for two vacancies.A voter has to vote for two candidates.In how many ways can on cast his vote ?

I used combination to solve this question using C$(6,2)$.

 But according to relation of permutation and combination$\displaystyle\frac{C(n,r)}{r!}=P(n,r)$.I could solve using permutation as $\displaystyle\frac{P(6,2)}{2!}$.

I want to know what does $\displaystyle\frac{P(6,2)}{2!}$ it mean in logical terms(E.g Arrangement of 6 persons among 2 vacancies,but I couldn't digest use of 2! in this equation )

> > Please tell me use of 2! in this question in logical terms.

Comment: $P(6,2)$ would give the answer if the vacancies were distinct in some way (President and Treasurer, say).  If they are identical you must divide by $2!=2$ because the vote $(a,b)$ is the same as the vote $(b,a)$.

Comment: @lulu thanks  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this answer from @lulu
It must be divided by $2!$ because these two posts are identical(E.g (a,b)=(b,a))